# Pre-populate image field in the React js form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I am new in reactjs. i am trying to update the form. Everything is pre-populating except for image field. So I have displayed image on current image label.

[image]

as because image field is not pre-populating, due to this filling up the image have become mandatory.

below is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './updateitem.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class updateItem extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      description: '',
      price: '',
      image: '',
      message: "",
      id: '',
      image_to_display: '',

    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const itno = this.props.match.params.itno;
    const itemAPI = `${window.apiHost}/api/items/${itno}`;
    axios.get(itemAPI).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        name: res.data.result.item_detail.name,
        description: res.data.result.item_detail.description,
        price: res.data.result.item_detail.price,
        image: res.data.result.item_detail.image,
        id: res.data.result.item_detail.id,})
    })
  }

  onImageChange= (event)=>{

    this.setState({
      'image': event.target.files[0],
    })

  }

  handleChange= (event)=>{
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    })
  }

  handleUpdate = async (event)=>{
    console.log('handle update');
    const itno = this.props.match.params.itno;
    const itemAPI = `${window.apiHost}/api/items/${itno}/`;
    event.preventDefault();
    let form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('name', this.state.name);
    form_data.append('description', this.state.description);
    form_data.append('price', this.state.price);
    form_data.append('image', this.state.image, this.state.image.name);
    await axios.put(itemAPI,
      form_data, {headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }}).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        name: res.data.result.item_detail.name,
        description: res.data.result.item_detail.description,
        price: res.data.result.item_detail.price,
        image: res.data.result.item_detail.image,
        id: res.data.result.item_detail.id,
        message: res.data.result.message})})

    document.getElementById('update_message').innerHTML = this.state.message

}

  render(){
    return(

      <div className="main_div">
              <div className="title">
                <h1>Welcome to "Sadguru's Amrit-Tulya-Tea Shop"</h1>
              </div>
              <div id="update_message"></div>
              <div className='container con_class'>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleUpdate} encType="multipart/form-data" className='update_form'>
                  <h2>Update Form</h2>
                  <div className="body">
                    <div className="name"><p>Name:</p><input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} name="name"></input></div ><br></br>
                    <div className="desc"><p>Description: </p><textarea type="textarea" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleChange} name="description"></textarea></div><br></br>
                    <div className="price"><p>Price: </p><input type="text" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.handleChange} name="price"></input></div><br></br>
                    <div className="img"><p>Image: </p><input type="file" className="form-control" id="image"   onChange={(e)=>this.onImageChange(e)} name="image"  /></div>
                    <div className="_ext_img">Current Image<img src={this.state.image} alt="Card"/></div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="footer">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success update" >Update</button>
                    <Link to={`/items/${this.state.id}/`}>
                      <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" >Cancel</button>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>


    </div>

    )
  }
}

export default updateItem;
```

if i am filling up the form then it gets updated.

i want the image to be prefilled with the data coming from API. and filling up the image should be optional. if user is not filling it up, than same image should be updated.

Please help me on this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a default value for the file input. This is purposely done for security reasons, otherwise you could upload and submit a malicious file without the user's knowledge.

What you could do instead is work around this issue, e.g. the field doesn't need to be mandatory but you can have a default value for the image in your component's state, and simply add a message (and probably display the image) for the user below the form, that if no file is uploaded, the default one will be used.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pre-fill a file input, an uploaded file has to be selected by user manually. Besides, your API is most likely returns an image url, but file's input value is always a `File` instance.